# "http error:404 Prblem accessing/.Reason not found" while accessing any page/url AEM6.3

Tags: aem

I am working in AEM6.3 on a Redhat Linux system. I am getting a blank page when I try to access AEM after startup with this message-

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```

Also, when I use curl command- curl `http://localhost:4503/`

I get below output-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any error in error.log and stdout.log.

Below is the stdout file-

```
13.09.2017 22:46:33.947 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:41783] /127.0.0.1:36152>stop
13.09.2017 22:46:33.948 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:41783] /127.0.0.1:36152<OK
13.09.2017 22:46:33.952 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:41783] Apache Sling terminated, exiting Java VM
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
13.09.2017 22:50:15.167 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=crx-quickstart (command line)
13.09.2017 22:50:15.173 *INFO * [main] Starting Apache Sling in /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart
13.09.2017 22:50:15.178 *INFO * [main] Sling  Extension Lib Home : /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad/ext
13.09.2017 22:50:15.183 *INFO * [main] Checking launcher JAR in folder /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad
13.09.2017 22:50:15.202 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:36225] Apache Sling Control Listener started
13.09.2017 22:50:15.203 *INFO * [main] Existing launcher is up to date, using it: 5.6.0.2_6_10-B001 (org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar)
13.09.2017 22:50:15.205 *INFO * [main] Loading launcher class org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate from org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar
13.09.2017 22:50:15.205 *INFO * [main] External Libs Home (ext) is null or does not exists.
13.09.2017 22:50:15.222 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.properties=conf/sling.properties
13.09.2017 22:50:15.222 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=crx-quickstart
13.09.2017 22:50:15.223 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.launchpad=/mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad
13.09.2017 22:50:15.223 *INFO * [main] Setting org.osgi.service.http.port=4503
13.09.2017 22:50:15.223 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
13.09.2017 22:50:15.236 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 4503
13.09.2017 22:50:17.012 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.settings.impl.SlingSettingsServiceImpl Read Sling ID a491a8be-10ae-4736-bc87-5868855a67e4 from file /mnt/crx/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle1/data/sling.id.file
13.09.2017 22:50:17.031 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.settings.impl.SlingSettingsServiceImpl Active run modes: [qa, crx3, samplecontent, publish, crx3tar]
13.09.2017 22:50:17.066 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.commons.log.logback.internal.Activator LogbackManager initialized at bundle startup
13.09.2017 22:50:17.360 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] jcl.over.slf4j BundleEvent RESOLVED
13.09.2017 22:50:17.361 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] jcl.over.slf4j BundleEvent STARTING
13.09.2017 22:50:17.361 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] jcl.over.slf4j BundleEvent STARTED
13.09.2017 22:50:17.361 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.installer.core BundleEvent STARTING
```

It was working fine, but suddenly stopped working. What could be the reason? Is it something related to the diapatcher?

Thanks!

Comment: are you accessing AEM via the dispatcher or directly to your publisher? What content are you expecting to be displayed?

Comment: your pub is not available. Can you try /system/console and check if all bundles are in active state? The crx root folder usually has a property sling:redirect and sling:target pointing to /index.html. When we hit <host>:4503, it redirects to this sling:target. Check if this is different and if the respective page is also available. Last you need check error.log file to trobleshoot and errors thrown.

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash I am not able to access any url including crx/de and crx explorer. They also give the same error- http 404. When I try to access system/console, it is not taking the credentials and not giving any error in the error.log. I am sure the credentials are correct.. Is there any other way to resolve it?

Comment: Its your local host right? system/console doesnt open with admin/admin? Thru webdav it is possible to disable crx. But wondering why your felix console doesnt open. If it is not time consuming you can quickly delete the entire crx folder and restart your aem from scratch.

Comment: No, this is not my local. It's our QA environment. @SaravanaPrakash

Comment: Then definitely you may need to contact your devops/admin/infra person. Should be access issue only.